# Can't install php-xml for PHP7 (CentOS)

Tags: php, xml, dependencies

I have installed PHP7, and I want to install php-xml, but it won't let me because I still have conflicting traces of PHP 5.4 on my system, that I cannot get rid of.

Here is what it looks like when I try to run "yum install php-xml":

`$ sudo yum install php-xml
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, replace
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.fileplanet.com
     * epel: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
     * extras: mirror.fileplanet.com
     * ius: mirrors.kernel.org
     * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
     * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.math.princeton.edu
     * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.math.princeton.edu
     * updates: mirror.fileplanet.com
     * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7 for package: php-xml-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.19-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common  Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

I've even tried to remove the php-common and I just get:

`$ sudo yum remove php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, replace
    No Match for argument: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
    No Packages marked for removal`

So it conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64, yet php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 doens't exist. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Also, I noticed it says

```
<code>
Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
</code>
```

But I don't want it for php 5.4, I want it for PHP7.

Comment: try `install php70w-xml`

Comment: Hi castis, that worked.  Thanks so much.

Comment: How do I mark this as completed, so that the green checkmark shows up?

Comment: Ill add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've installed the [webtatic repo](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/), those php installations should be `php70w-<package>`.

`yum install php70w-xml` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

on Centos7 this works in my case:

```
yum install php-xml
```